# Insert filepath link into Dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filepath

I'm trying to build a dataframe with embeeded links to files in my computer.

I found some references in Stackoverflow of how to do it for websites, as follows:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: '<a href="http://example.com/{0}">link</a>'.format(x))
```

I tried to do a similar (and others) line of code to put a filepath into the dataframe, but no sucess:

```
df['<img src="vermelho.png"/>' + "BEYOND 3SIGMA"] = '<a href="' + new_folder + caract[i]+ ".png" +'">link</a>'
```

Other try:

```
df.ix[i,0] = df.ix[i,0].apply(lambda x:'<a href="{}{}.png">{}</a>'.format(new_folder,caract,threesigmas))
```

I'm using IPython.display to display the hyperlink. I also accept other suggestions of how to build table with hyperlinks to local path in the Ipython notebook itself.

Comment: I'm almost convinced it has relation to the size of the filepath.